# Angular2 rxjs/Subject , rxjs/Observable events not working across the parent and child router

Tags: javascript, typescript, angular

I want to Interact/Share Data/Communicate each other with components inside the app , that have so many child ROUTES (all are templateUrl based )

Tried so many methods just like  event emitter -  @Output() , nothing worked for me.

Finally I came to know that a shared service can solve this problem .

I am looking for something like this

```
Application >> Global Service
Application >> Router 1 Component  >> Router 1A CompChild >>  Router 1AA
Application >> Router 2 Component  >> Router 2A CompChild>>  Router 2AA
Application >> Router 3 Component  >> Router 3A CompChild >>  **Route 3AA**
```

```
$.broadcast('event_name',data); // Router 3AAComponent fire/broadcast/emit event

$allComponents.on('event_name',function(){ .... some event actions ....}): 
// All child component of application can subscribe to that event
```

this is the reference url : http://blog.lacolaco.net/post/event-broadcasting-in-angular-2/

Please help me to solve this

Comment: Check https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/component-communication.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ensure you have `GlobalService` only provided once at the root component. If you add it to providers of every component where you use it, each component gets it's own instance and if one subscribes its a different instance then where events are emitted and therefore doesn't get notified.

Angular2 DI maintains a **single instance per provider**

Comment: How can i do this , could you please give me an example ? i can learn from that .

Comment: See the link in the comment below your question.